# SQL Query For Values From Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a team_name column but I want to instead store the team_IDs of the same teams from column (team_ID) in a different table to use as a foreign key and then drop team_names. Here are some screenshots

The table I have (players):
[image]

The table I want to get the values of team_ID from (teams_in_league):

[image]

For each row where team_ID is null, I want that to be the ID of the team_name contained in the next column. What query can I use to achieve this? Team_ID is meant to be a foreign key btw

EDIT:
Extra info: there should be two tables, I'm going to add more columns to the second table. That's why I'm not joining the two tables.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the tables in an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE players p
INNER JOIN teams_in_league t
ON t.team_name = p.team_name
SET p.team_id = t.team_id
```

After you do the update, you can remove the column `team_name` from the table `players` because it is redundant:

```
ALTER TABLE players
DROP COLUMN team_name;
```

and make the column `team_id` of `players` a foreign key that references `team_id` of `teams_in_league`:

```
ALTER TABLE players
ADD FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams_in_league(team_id);
```

Comment: I want the tables to remain separate, that's why I'm using a foreign key. I'm going to add more columns to the second table.

Comment: @Xaeol The tables are separate. The column team_name will not be needed in players if you have the team_id.

Comment: I misunderstood your wording, your solution worked perfectly, thank you!